# Nested Custom Configuration Collections, ConfigurationElementCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net

Custom config gurus.  I'm struggling with a custom config that I need to contain nested collections.  Here's how I'd like to have my config:

```
<FingerprintConfigurationGroup>
   <FingerprintConfiguration outputStats="true">
      <tagParser>
         <tag name="link">
            <attribute name="rel" value="stylesheet" />
            <attribute name="rel" value="icon" />
         </tag>
      </tagParser>
   </FingerprintConfiguration>
</FingerprintConfigurationGroup>
```

I've got the basics of collections down as well as elements, but I'm struggling with nested collections.

<tagParser> is required and must contain at least 1 <Tag> that must contain at least 1 <attribute>

You may be thinking, he's going to run into key element issues.  I've already figured that part out.  In code I have a non-required element within "attribute" that is the key element using a new GUID for each "attribute".

Can anyone help?  Thanks in advance gurus.  Hope this makes sense.